# ¿Cómo hago para enviar líneas de comandos hacia mi aplicación después de que se inició?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de audio y luego de agregar al menú de Windows una opción para agregar archivos a la lista de reproducción (`"repro.exe" "%1" /Add`) necesito enviar este nuevo comando a la aplicación ya iniciada para que la ejecute.

Comment: Puedes solicitar el ingreso mediante una variable, no necesariamente por comandos. Si lo quieres controlar por comandos, debes verificar si tu repro.exe ya está abierto y en ese caso en el método main agregas el comando y aplicas tu lógica. Así entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar MonoOptions, es una librería que te permite hacer lo que necesitas. No te dejes engañar por el nombre (sirve tanto para mono como para windows), mira este artículo: http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2009/11/22/command-line-parsing-with-mono.options.aspx

Answer (score 1):

yo hice algo parecido, pero invocando a un "Servicio Windows", aquí como lo implemente:

**Servicio:**

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
 base.OnCustomCommand(command);
 if (command == 255)
 {
    //hacer algo
 }
}
```

**Cliente**: para invocar lo hice así:

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);
if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
  serviceController.ExecuteCommand(255);    
}
```

Puedes revisar este Link sobre el envió de comando a una aplicación:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Espero que sea ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: donde debo colocar el metodo protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)